# JavaScript BETA Azure Function Exception

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I created a new JavaScript `timerTrigger`. Ran it on version `~1` and it executed fine.

I switched the version to `BETA` and ran it again and got:

`2017-10-26T14:17:55  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2017-10-26T14:17:57.938 Function started (Id=b196bcc3-c8ae-493e-84c7-9e037dba7141)
2017-10-26T14:17:58.565 Exception while executing function: Functions.Wrike. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Worker process with pid 7820 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 6964 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 6436 exited with code 1). Worker process with pid 7820 exited with code 1.
2017-10-26T14:17:58.907 Function completed (Failure, Id=b196bcc3-c8ae-493e-84c7-9e037dba7141, Duration=957ms)`

This is my `index.js`:

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if(myTimer.isPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   

    context.done();
};
```

Comment: Looks like something might be broken in the backend. It took nearly a second to throw an error and your code is doing nothing, so it's likely the host never started correctly. I'm looking up your app to get more info.

Comment: Looks like all your Functions aren't happy... Could you confirm that you have WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION set to "8.4.0" or above?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Ah thank you. I thought I had already set it. Apologies. I set it to `8.5.0` but the same error persists.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I tried it on a diff Function App and it works. Seems like one of my configs messed it up. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT It is better that write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common issue in "beta" today is that your Node.js version ends up being incorrect. We're working on a couple of improvements for this, including defaulting to 8.4.0 in case you haven't set it and improving the error message when it doesn't set incorrectly somehow.

Be sure you've set your Node.js version for Azure Functions in beta to be greater than 8.4.0. We generally try to keep testing the latest version of 8.x and will "GA" 2.0 on the 8.x LTS.

Comment: February, I tried 8.9.4, 8.4.0 and 8.5.0 without success. Any plans to solve this?

Comment: Those should all work. I'd open a new question/github issue with details.